How to write "cat simple.bin | protoc --decode_raw" in windows?
How to provide output of a file for the next command in windows? For example I want to decode a raw binary file into a protobuf output. How do I do it?
cat simple.bin | protoc --decode_raw


Do you mean protoc --decode_raw < simple.bin ? And I acknowledge that piping in this way doesn't do as the question asks i.e. "provide output...for the next command", but: it presumably achieves what you want?

In short: Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) 7  up to v7.3.x only ever communicated via text with external programs in their object-based pipeline. External-program output was always decoded into .NET strings, line by line.
Therefore, in these versions you can not use the PowerShell pipeline (notably via | and >) when raw byte data must be sent to / received from external programs - it will get corrupted.
As a workaround, pass command lines to cmd.exe /c or sh -c that make use of their | and > operators.
See the linked duplicate for more information.

@MarcGravell: PowerShell doesn't support <

@mklement0 then instead of asking "in Windows", OP should ask "in powershell"

@MarcGravell: while that may have been better for clarity, note that the question is tagged powershell.

I was able to execute the above command in gitbash without any changes

Indeed. In cmd.exe you could have used type simple.bin | protoc --decode_raw, or, more simply and efficiently, as @MarcGravell suggested, protoc --decode_raw < simple.bin; the latter also works in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash. From PowerShell, as the linked duplicate shows, you can easily shell out to cmd.exe, for instance: cmd /c 'protoc --decode_raw < simple.bin'
